# Probability using Combinations: Drawing 3 coloured cards

Tags: probability, combinations

There is a deck of 30 cards:

- 10 Black numbered 1 to 10
- 10 White numbered 1 to 10
- 10 Red numbered 1 to 10

What is the probability of drawing 2,3,4,5 OR 3,4,5,6 OR 7,8,9,10?

- Condition: There should be no more than 1 red card.

My answer:

- Number of accepted draws for numbers: 3
- Number of accepted draws for colours: 4*3*3*3=108
- Number of all combinations: C(30,4)= 27405

Probability: (3*108)/27405

If there's something wrong or there's an easier way to solve it please let me know.

Many thanks

Comment: It is not as simple as you make out. Has this been given as a task to you ?

Comment: @true blue anil , I am not happy with the explanations I find on Pot Limit Omaha (PLO) math. They lack very important basic questions and answer which are extremely important in basic hand selection. Basic hand selection is a fundamental knowledge a PLO player should have. I like to be able to answer to my own questions. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom {30}{4}=27405$ ways to choose the $4$ cards from the deck.

Out of these, there are $\binom {10}{0} \binom {20}{4}+\binom {10}{1} \binom {20}{3}=16245$ ways to choose $4$ cards with no more than $1$ red card.

Let $A$ be the event we choose $4$ cards with no more than $1$ red card. So $P(A) = \frac{361}{609}$

Let $A_i, i=1,2,3$ be the event we choose $\{2,3,4,5\},\{3,4,5,6\},\{7,8,9,10\}$ respectively.

Each $A_i$ can occur in $\binom {3}{1} ^44!=1944$ ways.

$\implies \forall i=1,2,3$ $P(A_i)=\frac{1944}{27405}=\frac{72}{1015}$

We are looking for the

$P((A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3) \cap A)$

$=P(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|A)P(A)$

$=(P(A_1|A)+P(A_2|A)+P(A_3|A))P(A)$ because the events $A_i$ are mutually exclusive

$=(3 \times P(A_1|A))P(A)$

$=3 \times P(A_1 \cap A)$

$=3 \times P(A|A_1)P(A_1)$

So it suffices to calculate $P(A|A_1)$.

Given that we chose the set $\{2,3,4,5\}$, the event $A$ can occur in $\binom {2}{1} ^ 4 4! + \binom {2}{1} ^ 3 4!=576$ ways. So $P(A|A_1)= \frac{576}{16245}$

So let's hope my answer is correct: $3 \times \frac{576}{16245} \times \frac{72}{1015} = 0.0075...$

Comment: thank you so much for putting time answering to this question. I understood it to the point P rules are discussed. I could not understand the necessity of this part. I need to think about it.

Comment: @Yavar Yes, it is not as easy as it seems. I'm not sure if my answer is completely correct because It was done quickly, it was mostly to motivate you to think the problem through. It's not too difficult it just needs some time put into thinking of a way to count the possible ways of selecting the cards and the problem is practically solved.